# Is there a way I can make a resource call return a promise with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code and it returns a promise which is what I need for this call. Now I would like to make my call to $resource return a promise but I cannot get it to do what I am needing.

```
get: function (applicationId) {
   return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/TestAccounts/GetSelect',
      params: { applicationId: applicationId }
   });
}
```

My resource is coded like this:

```
var Test = $resource('/api/Tests', {}, {
   saveData: { method: 'PUT' },
   deleteData: { method: "DELETE", params: { testId: 0 } }
});
```

When I run the following and it correctly returns data into the resp variable. However this is not what I want.

```
 query: function (selectedSubject) {
    Test.query({ subjectId: selectedSubject },
       function (resp) {
          var aa = resp;
        }
    );
 }
```

**Q:** I would like to return a promise. Is there a way that I can make the $resource instead return a promise like the call $http does? What I am looking for is a promise so I can execute the following calling code:

```
testService.query($scope.selectedSubject)
   .then(function (result) {
      var a = result.data;
   }, function (result) {
      alert("Error: No data returned");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use $q service and modify the code as below and return a promise

```
query: function (selectedSubject) {

         var deferred = $q.defer();
        Test.query({ subjectId: selectedSubject },
           function (resp) {
              deferred.resolve(resp);
            }
        );
    return deferred.promise;
     }
```